# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'video')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video, undefined, mern

```
    import { ArrowBackOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
 import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"; import 
"./watch.scss";

export default function Watch() { const location = useLocation(); 
const movie = location.movie; return ( Home <video className="video" 
autoPlay progress controls src={ movie.video } /> ); }
```

I try to make it shows a video from the database using useLocation but it gives me an error saying "video" is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
autoPlay progress controls src={ movie?.video } /> ); }
```

Sources: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4scLeF6z0KI), [Website](https://codedocu.com/Software/Angular/Angular-Error/Solved_colon_-ERROR-TypeError_colon_-Cannot-read-property-title-of-undefined?2782)

Answer (score 0):

Problem for this is the movie props doesn't get passed. So first first in your link you need to use state in V6.

```
<Link to="/watch" state={{movie:movie }}>
```

and then in the Watch component like below

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './watch.scss';
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Watch = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const movie = location.state.movie;
  useEffect(()=>{    
     console.log("location",location);  
   },[]);

  return (
    <div className="watch">
        <div className="back-btn">
            <ArrowBackIosIcon />
            Home
        </div>
        <video
        className="video"
        autoPlay
        progress
        controls
        src={movie.video}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Watch
```

Hope this helps